# iphone core data: Displaying attributes as headings in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, attributes

I am using Core Data and want to display an Entity's attributes as TableView headings.

In the example below, "Color" has three attributes and I would like to display each of these (consistent, inconsistent and multicolored) as headings in a tableview.  I can access the 'values' in each of these attributes, but not the names of the attributes themselves. Help appreciated.

[image: Core Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSManagedObject.entity.attributesByName will return an NSDictionary with all the attribute names of the entity as the keys.

Comment: Pretty nifty. (Once you get that, NSDictionary has a method `allKeys` that returns an array of strings, just what you want.)

Comment: HI Steve.  I'm being thick.  What code would I use to extract attributeByname in to a dictionary?  Many thanks.

Comment: attributesByName already returns an NSDictionary so I'm not sure I understand your question.